# Return Observation With Most Recent Date in each group

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I've tried the following code and unfortunately it spot checked in a few places , but not all.

```
proc sql;
create table AgedPrep AS
SELECT * , MAX(report_date) AS Latest_dt format date9.
FROM WORK.What_We_Have 
GROUP BY Name 
;
quit;


proc sql;
create table Aged_Want AS
SELECT * 
FROM WORK.AgedPrep
Where Latest_dt = report_date
;
quit;
```

We have the following data

```
  Name  Report_Date  Outcome
  Brian  11/12/13    good
  Brian  11/14/14    bad
  sussie  9/12/20    good
  sussie  12/11/19   bad
```

we want the following

```
  Name  Report_Date  Outcome
  Brian  11/14/14    bad
  sussie  9/12/20    good
```

Pretty classic select only the row with the most recent date for each group. I've gotten this right before but cannot seem to get it now.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple version using base SAS code.

```
proc sort data=have;
   by name descending report_date;

data want;
   set have;
   by name;
   if first.name;
run;
```

Comment: wow, I don't know why I was so stuck on wanting to use proc SQL and the max() function.  I was trying to avoid the move where people rejoin a table to itself. I am a bit embarrassed now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `having` clause and SAS SQL automatic remerge. having logic will be applied group wise when there is a `GROUP BY`

Example:

```
  create table want AS
  SELECT *
  from have
  group by name
  having report_date = max(report_date)
```